# How this non-existing getter method becomes available

Tags: java

I'm just getting my self familiarized with the code base of our application and I found this one Java class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = SqlTables.PRODUCTS)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Schedule {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @NotBlank(message = "name should not be empty")
  private String name;

  private boolean recurring;
```

An instance of the above class can be passed as method parameter to other classes e.g.:

```
private void validateRecurringAttribute(Schedule schedule) {
    if (schedule.isRecurring()) {
      log.error("[ERROR] <validateRecurringAttribute()> Recurring schedule is not yet supported.");
      throw new UnsupportedException("Recurring schedule is not yet supported.");
    }
  }
```

What I'm wondering is this getter method - `isRecurring()`, it is not available in the `Schedule` class but somehow can be called in other classes. How is it done?

Comment: What do you think the purpose of all those annotations on the class is? Especially the one named @ Getter?

Comment: And honestly, why didn't you first ask the members of your team?

Comment: IsRecurring() is callable in Schedule class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These `Getters` and `Setters` of the class data members are generated by the `@Setter` and `@Getter` annotation of Lombok.

Further you can use `@Data` which implicitly calls

```
@Getter 
@Setter 
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ToString
```

Basically we are using these annotation of lombok to remove boilerplate code.

Example:

```
@Data
Class tax{
 private int tax;
}
```

Now we don't need to explicitly define getter and setters for it like.

```
private int gettax(){
    return tax;
}
private void settax(int tax){
    this.tax = tax;
}
```

https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Answer (score 4):

The getters and setters are generated at compile time by these 2 lombok annotations in the class -

```
@Setter
@Getter
```

To know more about Lombok and getter setter -

https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter

Comment: So these are definitely lombok annotations? Spring doesn't have that?

Comment: @GhostCat Absolutely.  The only annotations shown are from Lombok (`@Getter`, `@Setter`, `@Builder`, `@NoArgsConstructor`, `@AllArgsConstructor`), JPA (`@Entity`, `@Table`, `@Id`, `@GeneratedValue`), Jackson (`@JsonNaming`), and JavaEE Validation (`@NotBlank`).

Comment: I don't think Spring has any @Getter annotation. But these annotation being coming from  Lombok is a guess actually since it's most commonly used. It can be from `anywhere`.

Better the author look at the import paths. The reference to Lombok will guide to the correct direction at least.